# Unable to access webservice from Azure WebSite

Tags: web-services, wcf, azure

I have an website hosted in Azure Websites. I am trying to connect to an external webservice, and am getting the message:

> There was no endpoint listening at https://myexternalservice.com/ws/

I am able to run this locally, and connect no problem, but having an issue only Azure.

My current binding is a `basicHttpBinding` defined as such

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" openTimeout="00:10:00"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000" />
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://myexternalservice.com/ws" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" contract="MyContract" name="MyEndpointName" />
</client>
```

I'm going to presume this is some sort of internal load balancing that is preventing me from accessing this external address??

Hope someone can help

**EDIT**
OK, I've tried going onto the Debug console (i.e. mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net) and opening a CMD window. I've tried the following:

`nslookup myexternalservice.com`

and getting the following:

> Server:  UnKnown
>   Address:  10.20.201.9

For mine, this looks to be completely an Azure issue. Anyone else come across a similar type problem?

In the meantime I've reluctantly updated by endpoint address to be bound directly to the IP address, and this has worked, but is not a viable solution going forward. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh - and just to make this trickier to diagnose... this is temperamental. I.e. it has worked previously (and it has thrown this exception before too - it just 'fixed itself' previously)